# French QWERTY keyboard for Nexus S

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, keyboard, samsung-nexus-s

When using the French language the default virtual keyboard on the Nexus S use the AZERTY keyboard layout.

That might be fine in Europe but not in North America (e.g. Quebec) where everyone uses QWERTY keyboards.

How can we globally change the keyboard layout on the Nexus S ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your phone is rooted, it's possible to do this by modifying system files that govern the keyboard.  A much easier (and safer) way would be installing a 3rd-party keyboard replacement app that has a French QWERTY layout.

Out of keyboards I've personally used, I can recommend [AnySoftKeyboard](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.menny.android.anysoftkeyboard) with [French Language Pack](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.anysoftkeyboard.languagepack.french). It includes both AZERTY and QWERTY (French-Canadian) layouts.