# How can I change a QWERTY keyboard layout to AZERTY without changing the phone language?

Tags: keyboard, localization

I've just acquired an HTC Desire with MIUI interface.

I speak English and want the phone to stay in English. But I live in France and all my keyboards (computers, etc.) are French standard AZERTY, not QWERTY.

The phone shows a QWERTY keyboard.  Having the phone in QWERTY is confusing.

How can I change the phone keyboard to AZERTY without changing the language of the phone into French please?

Answer (score 6):

SwiftKey X supports the feature you are asking (English with AZERTY keyboard).  Try out their [demo](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.touchtype.swiftkey.phone.trial&feature=more_from_developer#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwMiwiY29tLnRvdWNodHlwZS5zd2lmdGtleS5waG9uZS50cmlhbCJd).

After you have installed the app, go to the Settings of SwiftKey.  Go to "Languages & layouts"

Next to Englush, tap on the little keyboard icon.  Then choose AZERTY.

You'll now have English autocorrect on an AZERTY keyboard.

Comment: Also, thanks for posting the question, now I know how to get French autocorrect on a QWERTY keyboard :D Now, if only Swype supported it....

Comment: Swift Key X Free seems to work, but comes up Swiftkey Trial.  So will it revert in a month or so?

Comment: No idea, I'm not an active SwiftKey user. I think after the Trial you'd have to purchase the paid version, $1.99 https://market.android.com/details?id=com.touchtype.swiftkey&feature=more_from_developer#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwMiwiY29tLnRvdWNodHlwZS5zd2lmdGtleSJd but I could be wrong

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar [question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/16070/9400) where I wanted to switch from AZERTY to QWERTY. I think the same suggested *free* software (from the answer) will serve you well (like it did for me).